# Node.js quick consecutive PUT requests not executed correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The app is written in Node.js using Express. I'm also using MongoDB and Mongoose.

There is a PUT endpoint which updates the user's information such as the user's firstname, age, etc. and the cars he/she likes and how much each car costs. The endpoint receives an array called newProfileData as shown below.

```
router.put(
  "/",
  middleware.verifyToken,
  [check("newProfileData").not().isEmpty().trim().escape()],
  async function (req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json(errors.array());
    }

    try {
// update profile collection if the firstname has changed
// also update likedCars collection if the user adds new cars; doing this by sending a fetch post request to the /addCar endpoint 
// if the liked car is Aston Martin then send a post request to add Aston Martin
fetch(process.env.APPLICATIONURL + "cars/add", {
                    method: "post",
                    body: JSON.stringify(carData),
                    headers: {
                      Authorization: "Bearer " + req.bearerToken,
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                  })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((dataObj) => {
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log(err);
                      return res.status(422).json("Could not update.");
                    });

// if the liked car is Ferrari send another fetch request
fetch(process.env.APPLICATIONURL + "cars/add", {
                    method: "post",
                    body: JSON.stringify(carData),
                    headers: {
                      Authorization: "Bearer " + req.bearerToken,
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                  })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((dataObj) => {
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log(err);
                      return res.status(422).json("Could not update.");
                    });


} catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(422).json(err);
    }
  }
);
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to make separate fetch requests because of the way I receive the data from frontend. If I add just one car and send just one fetch request the "cars/add" endpoint works fine, but if I add multiple cars, the data gets overwritten somehow in the "cars/add" endpoint and if I start adding console logs to debug, the code runs in even a weirder way by adding one car and not the other, but if I try the code multiple times then it changes which car gets added. Please see the "cars/add" endpoint below:

```
router.post(
  "/add",
  middleware.verifyToken,
  [
    check("carData").not().isEmpty().trim().escape(),
  ],
  async function (req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json(errors.array());
    }
    try {
      let userID = req.tokenData.userID;
      let user = await User.findOne({ _id: userID });
      if (user === null || user.length <= 0) {
        return res.status(422).json("Could not fetch user");
      } else {
        let type = await CarType.findOne({ name: req.body.type });

        if (type === null || type === undefined || type.length < 1) {
          return res.status(422).json("Could not fetch car type");
        }

        let carData = JSON.parse(req.body.carData);

        for (newRes of carData) {
          let carResult = await Car.findOne({
            friendlyName: newRes.carName,
          });

          if (!carResult)
            return res.status(422).json("Could not fetch car");
          newRes.car = carResult;
        }
        
        let likesCreated = await CarLikes.create({
          
          cars: carData,
        });
       

        if (
          likesCreated === undefined ||
          likesCreated === null ||
          likesCreated.length <= 0
        ) {
          return res.status(422).json("Could not add cars");
        } else {
          likesCreated.userID = user;
          likesCreated.save();
          return res.status(200).json("Success");
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(422).json(err);
    }
  }
);
```

The problem happens when I send two or more consecutive fetches. Most of the time the "newRes.car = carResult;" is ignored and I do not have the car key added to newRes for the first car sent by the first fetch, but it gets added for the second car from the second fetch.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out what the problem was...

This line of code

```
for (newRes of carData)
```

needs to be changed to

```
for (let newRes of carData)
```

otherwise newRes is stored as a global variable...